# rsyslog server and client not working when roles are switched

Tags: linux, centos, rsyslog

I have two CentOS-7 machines. I have configured one as a rsyslog server and the other as rsyslog client.
I am using UDP/514.
In rsyslog server machine I have added the following entries in the /etc/rsyslog.conf file:

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/RemoteHost/%fromhost%/programname/%programname%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs
```

And in the ryslog client machine I have added the following entry

```
*.* @<server-IP-address>:514
```

Everything is working fine, and I can receive remote logs from the client.

Then, I switched the roles of both the machines. I made the old rsyslog server as new rsyslog client and vice versa, by adding the same entries mentioned above.

But, I am not receiving any remote logs from the client now (only the local logs of the server machine is received in the /var/log/RemoteHost directory).

And the rsyslog service is still active without any errors.

I don't know what's going wrong. Is there any extra changes that needs to be done in this case?

Comment: are you using SELinux?  Is there anything listening on the server host on 514 (```netstat -an | grep 514```)

Comment: SELinux is enabled. and the output of the above command is 

`udp     0     0 0.0.0.0:514           0.0.0.0:*`
and
`udp6    0     0 :::514                   :::*`

Comment: the line you're using for forwarding: ```*.* @<server-IP-address>:514``` is apparently outdated.  Try changing to ```*.* action(type="omfwd" target="<server-IP-address>" port="514" protocol="udp")``` --- [source](https://www.rsyslog.com/sending-messages-to-a-remote-syslog-server/)